# python script to exclude specific field of csv cell data

Tags: python, csv

using python I'm trying to create summary with existing data of `csv` and finding difficulties in extracting data from one of the cell.

the input csv file
[image]

I want to include only the city name and file path from info 4 column and expecting the summary like - `AlexxxxxyyyyzzzzzNewyork\Folder1\Folder2\Test.txt`

the code

```
csv_data_out[csv_line_out].append(conten[Name])
csv_data_out[csv_line_out].append(conten[info 1])
csv_data_out[csv_line_out].append(conten[info 2])
csv_data_out[csv_line_out].append(conten[info 3])
csv_data_out[csv_line_out].append(conten[info 4])
csv_summary = ("".join(csv_data_out[csv_line_out]))

with open(outputfile, 'wb') as newfile:
   writer = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter = ';')
   writer.writerow(csv_columns_out[:])
   writer.writerows(csv_data_out)
newfile.close()
```

any idea to fetch only the required details from info 4 col ?

Comment: Try using a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have a csv inside a csv. There's not info posted to give a fully complete answer but here's most of it.

You can take a string and process it as a csv using io.StringIO (or io.BytesIO if a byte string).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
from io import StringIO

# Create somewhere to put the inputs in case needed later
stored_items = []

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    inputs = csv.reader(csvfile)
    
    # skip the header row
    next(inputs)
    
    for row in inputs:
        # Extract the Info 4 column for processing
        f = StringIO(row[4])
        string_file = csv.reader(f,quotechar='"')
        build_string = ""
        for string_row in string_file:
            build_string =  f"{string_row[0]}{string_row[1]}"
        # Merge everything into a summary
        summary_string = f"{row[0]}{row[1]}{row[2]}{row[3]}{build_string}"
        # Add all the data back to storage
        stored_items.append((row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],summary_string))
        print(summary_string)
```

The reason why I say there's not enough information posted in because, for example, will the location always be `(a)`  which can have a fixed text replacement, or will be conditional e.g. it could be `(a)`  or `(b)`  in which case it would possibly require regex. (My preference is not to use regex unless absolutely necessary). Also, is it always the first two terms you are after from `Info 4`, or will the terms be found in different places in the text etc. Without seeing more samples of the data it's impossible to answer definitely.